# How to Connect to a Sign In User Flow

Tags: java, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I'm authenticating a Java Web App using MSAL4J with success using the /authorize endpoint to obtain both the ID and Access tokens.

But I did not found any Java example for connecting to a given User's Flow defined in Azure AD B2C.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this [MSAL4J B2C sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-java-webapp/tree/master/msal-b2c-web-sample)?

Here are where the [user flows/policies](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-java-webapp/blob/ceebdc8d7e04e9662111e2e3ff9e90303efae3e1/msal-b2c-web-sample/src/main/resources/application.properties#L13) are defined for the sample. In the AAD B2C portal, you will define the user flows and applications. In MSAL4J, you will construct the authority using the user flow/policy, as each user flow/policy is a separate token issuer in B2C.

B2C MSAL4J authority [example](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-java-webapp/blob/ceebdc8d7e04e9662111e2e3ff9e90303efae3e1/msal-b2c-web-sample/src/main/resources/application.properties#L17)